# Why do I have to declare another string comparison in my loop statement?

Tags: java, while-loop, string-comparison

So our professor was making us do a loop where in we will ask a question if we want to continue, and if the user inputs "Y" it will ask again and so on.. But once the user inputs "N", it will say "Good Bye!".. I tried using the if statement and when the user inputs "N" it will ask again, it didn't end with "Good Bye!". So after stumbling upon here and managed to get it work.. I just wanna ask, why do I have to put `input.equals("Y");` inside the loop statement?

Thank you in advance!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

    public class While{
    public static void main(String Args[]){

        String input;
        String b="Y";
        String c="N";
        Scanner get=new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Please enter 'Y' for YES and 'N' for NO.");
            System.out.print("Do you want to continue? ");
            input = get.nextLine().toUpperCase();

            while (input.equals(b))
            {
                input.equals("Y");
                System.out.print("Do you want to continue? ");
                input = get.nextLine().toUpperCase();
            }

            System.out.println("Good Bye!");
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't. That line does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input.equals("Y")` just checks whether `input` equals `"Y"` and returns `true` if it does, `false` otherwise. But since you do not use the return value of `.equals` at all, this line is completely useless.

Comment: Ooh oki doki! Thank youu! :D